How do I define a Decimal type in a SharePoint List?
I am making an API GET call.  In Postman, I get a response and according to the data I receive, I can safely assume what the data types are.  In the screen shot snip below I can assume that

TripID is an integer
External Reference is a string
OffBlocksUtc is a DateTime class
FlyingTimePinned is a boolean type

etc.

But the FlyingTime is some sort of floating point type. When I looked at the XML data that "@odata.context" references, I find that it is described as a Decimal type.
This postman test is used in my C# code and in that code I want to use my results to create columns in a SharePoint List.  But I do not see imediately what type will work.  Will the Number type still work for a floating point decimal type?
Here are the SharePoint List column types described directly from Microsoft:

